# addInterceptors is not called in spring boot 2.1.1 auto configuration

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

I am writing a spring-boot start which aims at auto configuring interceptors for handlers. The main class looks like the following:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MetricsProperties.class)
public class MetricsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MetricsConfiguration.class);

    private final MetricsProperties metricsProperties;

    public MetricsConfiguration(MetricsProperties properties) {
        this.metricsProperties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public MetricsCenter createMetricsCenter() {
        MetricsCenter metricsCenter = MetricsCenter.getInstance();
        metricsCenter.init(metricsProperties);
        return metricsCenter;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        logger.error("alex add");   // the log does not appear!!
        registry.addInterceptor(new MetricsInterceptor());
    }
}
```

according to the document

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration

which says:

> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features and you want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers, and other features), you can add your own @Configuration class of type WebMvcConfigurer but without @EnableWebMvc. If you wish to provide custom instances of RequestMappingHandlerMapping, RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, or ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver, you can declare a WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter instance to provide such components.

I did as what the document says, but the `addInterceptors` is not called and my interceptor is not equipped with spring mvc.

Can someone help me out of here, please?

thx.

Comment: Just to rule out errors coming from the `ConditionalOnWebApplication`, can you put a log statement or breakpoint into the existing or a temporarily included default constructor to see if the configuration class is active at all?

Answer (score 9):

You may have a custom `@Configuration` class (e.g. in the consumer of your starter) extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class in which case it takes the full control and your `WebMvcConfigurer`s don't get called.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.